# Procedure problem ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create reschedule procedure for AQ queues. So i have created procedure with one IN parameter where our operator will enter just a name of queue, and i hit error when i execute create of procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RESCHEDULE1 (p_queue IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
   SYS.DBMS_AQADM.STOP_QUEUE (p_queue);
END;



DECLARE
   CURSOR upit
   IS
      SELECT destination
        FROM USER_QUEUE_SCHEDULES
       WHERE qname = p_queue;
BEGIN
   FOR dest_rec IN upit
   LOOP
      DBMS_AQADM.UNSCHEDULE_PROPAGATION (queue_name   => p_queue,
                                         destination  => dest_rec.destination);



      DBMS_AQADM.SCHEDULE_PROPAGATION (queue_name   => p_queue,
                                       destination  => dest_rec.destination,
                                       start_time   => SYSDATE);
   END LOOP;
END;

;

BEGIN
   SYS.DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (p_queue);
END;
/
```

Error is

```
ORA-06550: line 7, column 39:

PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "P_QUEUE": invalid identifier

ORA-06550: line 5, column 4:

PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

ORA-06550: line 14, column 54:

PLS-00201: identifier 'P_QUEUE' must be declared

ORA-06550: line 14, column 2:

PL/SQL: Statement ignored

ORA-06550: line 17, column 52:

PLS-00201: identifier 'P_QUEUE' must be declared

ORA-06550: line 17, column 2:

PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: *"I hit error when i execute create of procedure."* In your example you have one procedure and an anonymous block. Do you mean the anonymous block is failing to compile?

Answer (score 2):

`p_queue` is out of scope everywhere, except in `RESCHEDULE1` procedure. You have to pass its value, somehow.

One option is this: instead of using an anonymous PL/SQL blocks, switch to procedures (and - of course - declare the `p_queue` parameter).

Comment: Could you please tell me how you would manage this, by using my procedure code?

Comment: As I said: instead of anonymous PL/SQL procedures (those are `declare - begin - end` structures), make procedures out of them (`create procedure ... begin ... end`). You can use code you've already written, just put `create procedure some_name` instead of `declare`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your procedure has improper use of `BEGIN..END` and `DECLARE`

Try following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RESCHEDULE1 (p_queue IN VARCHAR2)
AS 
-- all declarations should go here
   CURSOR upit
   IS
      SELECT destination
        FROM USER_QUEUE_SCHEDULES
       WHERE qname = p_queue;
BEGIN -- starting of procedure
   BEGIN -- starting of this block -- can be removed
      SYS.DBMS_AQADM.STOP_QUEUE (p_queue);
   END; -- ending of this block -- can be removed 

   FOR dest_rec IN upit -- loop started from here
   LOOP
      DBMS_AQADM.UNSCHEDULE_PROPAGATION (queue_name   => p_queue,
                                         destination  => dest_rec.destination); 

      DBMS_AQADM.SCHEDULE_PROPAGATION (queue_name   => p_queue,
                                 destination  => dest_rec.destination,
                                 start_time   => SYSDATE);

   END LOOP; -- loop ends here

   BEGIN -- starting of this block -- can be removed  
      SYS.DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (p_queue);
   END; -- ending of this block  -- can be removed 

END RESCHEDULE1; -- end of procedure
/
```

**Note:** You can remove unnecessary `BEGIN` and `END` from code if you dont want to handle exceptions.

I have kept all `BEGIN` and `END` in procedure as it is, considering tht you actually need it for future development.

Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

Please sorry i didnt post that i have found answer, problem was with bad begin and end. Now this works

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AQADMIN.RESCHEDULE1  (p_queue in varchar2)
            is

    begin

    begin
     DBMS_AQADM.STOP_QUEUE(p_queue); 
    end;


     declare
    cursor upit
    is 
       SELECT destination 
                             FROM USER_QUEUE_SCHEDULES
                            WHERE qname = p_queue ;


    begin

    for dest_rec in upit
    loop


     DBMS_AQADM.UNSCHEDULE_PROPAGATION (queue_name    => p_queue,
                                          destination   => dest_rec.destination);

     DBMS_AQADM.SCHEDULE_PROPAGATION (queue_name    => p_queue,
                                        destination   => dest_rec.destination,
                                        start_time    => SYSDATE);
    end loop;
    end;

    begin
    DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (p_queue);
    end;

    end;
    /
```

Thank you for all your help!